# Select where greater than and until

Tags: mysql, database

I got stuck for get the result about select where greater than and until
for example, this is my data looks like

```
id    profile_id    status     created_at                   updated_at
1         1           2        31/12/2018  03.38.02   31/12/2018  03.38.02
2         1           4        01/01/2019  03.38.02   01/01/2019  03.38.02
3         1           2        02/01/2019  03.38.02   02/01/2019  03.38.02
4         1           4        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
5         1           5        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
6         1           4        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
```

I want get the result like this, and rows have before last status = 4 show all value afterwards until meet status 4

```
 5         1           5        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
 6         1           4        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
```

for now, I have tried like this but have not succeeded, the query like this

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `profiles` 
WHERE `created_at` > 
  (SELECT 
    `created_at` 
  FROM
    `profiles` 
  WHERE `status` IN ('4') 
    AND `profile_id` = '1'
  ORDER BY `from` DESC 
  LIMIT 1) 
  AND `profile_id` = '1'
  AND `status` IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
ORDER BY `from` ASC
```

and result empty

and if I modify the data like this

```
id    profile_id    status     created_at                   updated_at
1         1           2        31/12/2018  03.38.02   31/12/2018  03.38.02
2         1           4        01/01/2019  03.38.02   01/01/2019  03.38.02
3         1           2        02/01/2019  03.38.02   02/01/2019  03.38.02
4         1           4        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
5         1           5        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
*6         1           2        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02*
```

And the result with my query like that

```
 5         1           5        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
 6         1           2        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
```

Of course the results that I expect are not like that, I want the results without modifying the previous data, which is displaying

```
 5         1           5        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
 6         1           4        03/01/2019  03.38.02   03/01/2019  03.38.02
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want a query ordered on updated_at find the first status that is 4 and then show the rest of the table until the status is lower than 4?